# How to open an app from another app in android?

Tags: android

I have an application named as "App" and another application named as "App1", I have a button in "App" when I click that button I want to open "App1", for this I am using Intent but it does not open "App1".Please help

here is my code for button in "App":-

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app);
    init();
}
public void init(){
    mTranslucentBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mTranslucentBtn.setAlpha(0.7f);
    mTranslucentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){//calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
            startNewActivity(MainActivity.this,"com.example.devui1.rewardapp");

        }
    });
}
public void startNewActivity(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (intent == null) {
        // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: See this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Answer (score 0):

In order for `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` to work, that package needs to have an Activity that is suitable for being launched as an entry point into that app. The documentation includes this:

> The current implementation looks first for a main activity in the category CATEGORY_INFO, and next for a main activity in the category CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. Returns null if neither are found.

This suggests you need one of the following on an Activity in your other package:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
</intent-filter>
```

Or

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If that's not something you want, then you could try creating your own custom action string and using that to launch an activity exposing that specific action:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="your.package.ACTION_NAME" />
</intent-filter>

public void startActivityWithPrivateAction(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("your.package.ACTION_NAME");
    intent.setPackage(packageName);
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (activities.isEmpty() {
        // no suitable activity was found; open the market instead.
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```